# Combining data sets using an ID with multiple possible names

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, data-cleaning

I have two data sets, both with dog breed names. I'd like to combine the data sets somehow, but a lot of dogs have multiple names, so for instance African Hairless Dogs are also called African Abyssinian Terriers.

I think these names are too different to match by the similarity of their words, so I'm wondering what's the best way to match them.

So for instance, suppose data set 1 is

```
Breed                           Height (inches)
------------------------------------------------                 
Golden Retriever                20 
Labrador Retriever              22
African Hairless Dog            17
```

And data set 2 is

```
Breed                           Weight (pounds)
------------------------------------------------               
African Abyssinian Terrier      30 
Golden Retriever                60 
Labrador Retriever              65
```

I'd like a data set like the following below:

```
Breed                           Height (inches)           Weight (pounds)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------              
African Hairless Dog            17                        30
Golden Retriever                20                        60
Labrador Retriever              22                        65
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique `id` column variable in the two data frames, then `left_join` should do the trick. E.g.

```
df1 = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), breed = c("African  Abyssinian Terrier", "Golden Retriever","Labrador Retriever"), height= c(17, 20 , 22))

df2 = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), breed = c("African Hairless Dog", "Golden Retriever","Labrador Retriever"), weight = c(30, 60 , 65))

library(dplyr)
```

```
> df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c("id" = "id"))
  id                     breed.x height              breed.y weight
1  1 African  Abyssinian Terrier     17 African Hairless Dog     30
2  2            Golden Retriever     20     Golden Retriever     60
3  3          Labrador Retriever     22   Labrador Retriever     65
```

You can do a bit of cleaning up if you want

```
df3 = df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("id" = "id")) %>% 
  select(-breed.y) %>% 
  rename(breed = breed.x)
```

```
> df3
  id                       breed height weight
1  1 African  Abyssinian Terrier     17     30
2  2            Golden Retriever     20     60
3  3          Labrador Retriever     22     65
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. Is the join being done by id number? Because I'd like it generalized enough so that you aren't matching by id number, rather by breed name. I'll edit the question to make this more explicit.

Comment: Yes, the join is being done by `id` rather than `name`. What you would like to do a much much harder problem, because I expect the concept of breed similarity is really quite specific :-)

Comment: Ah yes I'm afraid I'm looking for the latter. Thanks for helping though!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution based on James Curran's answer. Create a data frame, `df3`, that contains all possible nicknames of a breed per row, as well as a unique id number. Use `filter_all` to filter for the unique id number from each data set, then join each data set using the unique id number.

```
df1 <- data.frame(breed = c("Labrador Retriever", "GR","African Abyssinian"), height= c(17, 20 , 22))

df2 <- data.frame(breed = c("African Hairless Dog", "Golden Retriever","Labrador Retriever"), weight = c(30, 60 , 65))

#create data frame, df3
df3 <- data.frame(id = 1:3, breed1 = c("African Hairless Dog", "Golden Retriever","Labrador Retriever"), breed2 = c("African Abyssinian Terrier", "GR","LR"))

id1 <- data.frame()
id2 <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:3){
  id <- df3 %>% filter_all(any_vars(grepl(df1$breed[i],.))) %>% select(id)
  id <- cbind(id,df1$breed[i]) %>% rename(breed = `df1$breed[i]`)
  id1 <- rbind(id1,id)

  id <- df3 %>% filter_all(any_vars(grepl(df2$breed[i],.))) %>% select(id)
  id <- cbind(id,df2$breed[i]) %>% rename(breed = `df2$breed[i]`)
  id2 <- rbind(id2,id)
}

df1 <- left_join(df1,id1) #keep breed name from this data set
df2 <- left_join(df2,id2) %>% select(-breed)

final_data_frame <- left_join(df1,df2, by=c('id'))
```

If anyone has a more elegant solution that would also be much appreciated!